# PHP misreads quotes in HTML string

Tags: php, html, string, escaping

PHP hangs after that first echo statement because the last quote there is the first one it sees. As a result, my query doesn't get executed. What's going on?

```
    <html>
    <head><title>New.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

      $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "password");

   if (!$connect) {
    die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");
    alert("No access.");
   }

   mysql_select_db("db");

   echo "<div class=\"accwrapper\">";
   echo "<div id=\"resor\">";

    $rresult=mysql_query("SELECT * from node");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

   echo "<tr class=\"prislista-row\"><td>";

   echo $row["node_title"];

   echo "</td><td class=\"list-price\">";

   echo $row["uc_products_list_price"];

    echo "</td><td class=\"sell-price\">";

     echo $row["uc_products_sell_price"];

     echo "</td></tr>";

  }

   ?>  
   </div><!--resor-->

    </div><!--accwrapper-->

   </body>
```

EDIT: Everything after

```
          echo '<div class="accwrapper">'; //the last single quote in this line
```

is a string, even with single quotes. Removed single quotes and the alert/die thing and still no luck. But thanks to everyone's responses.

Comment: You mean `echo "<div class=\"accwrapper\">";`? I don't see a problem with it. What's the error message? You can also write `echo '<div class="accwrapper">';` so you don't have to escape double quotes.

Comment: what do you mean by _because the last quote there is the first one it sees_

Comment: remove or comment alert("No access.");

Comment: Which error message do you get? If none, enable error reporting, the error log and/or display errors. Then look for which message you get. If there is a syntax error (e.g. with strings), this will get highlighted and give you a line number.

Comment: Might be a good opportunity to read up on HEREDOC strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes around your echo's then you won't have to excape

```
     echo '</td><td class="sell-price">';
```

but the main problem is alert is a javascript function not a php

remove this line

```
   alert("No access.");
```

**EDIT**

I took out your mysql stuff and it works so now you just gotta figure out whats wrong with your sql

```
  <html>
  <head><title>New.</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php

   $connect = true;

if (!$connect) {
 die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");
}

//mysql_select_db("db");


     echo '<div class="accwrapper">';
     echo '<div id="resor">';


    echo '<tr class="prislista-row"><td>';

    echo $row["node_title"];

    echo '</td><td class="list-price">';

    echo $row["uc_products_list_price"];

    echo '</td><td class="sell-price">';

    echo $row["uc_products_sell_price"];

    echo '</td></tr>';



 ?>  
 </div><!--resor-->

  </div><!--accwrapper-->

 </body>
```

Comment: Even if it were a PHP function it wouldn't do anything because there's a `die()` command right before it.

Comment: @Juhana that is true but it is still a problem as the function is not defined

Comment: Removed die/alert command and changed to single quotes, still no dice.

Comment: What do you mean by 'No dice'?  When I run the code, I get the can't connect error message, not a PHP error.  Is that what's happening to you?  Are you certain you are connecting to the database correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using echo tags, try using single quotes eg:

```
 echo '<div class="accwrapper">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing it this way should never cause problem ;) :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>New.</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <?php
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "password");

   if (!$connect) {
    die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");
    alert("No access.");  //this will never execute
   }

   mysql_select_db("db");
   $rresult=mysql_query("SELECT * from node");
  ?>   

   <div class="accwrapper">
   <div id="resor">

   <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))  : ?>
   <tr class="prislista-row">
     <td><?php echo $row["node_title"]; ?></td>
     <td class="list-price"><?php echo $row["uc_products_list_price"]; ?></td>
     <td class="sell-price"><?php echo $row["uc_products_sell_price"]; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php endwhile; ?>  

   </div><!--resor-->
</div><!--accwrapper-->
```

So let HTML be HTML, and PHP should stay PHP. Try to avoid mixing them like by echoing HTML from within PHP.